# jquery loop within loop sharepoint

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to loop thru the webpart to get a table.. I have the below code as of now..

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Team');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Count');

  var dataWebPartId = '********************************';

  var arrayList = $("div[WebPartId='" + dataWebPartId + "'] td.ms-gb:contains('Status')");

  $.each(arrayList, function(i, e) {

    var groupHeader = $(e).text();
    var lable = groupHeader.substring(groupHeader.indexOf(':') + 2, groupHeader.indexOf("(") - 1);
    var value = groupHeader.substring(groupHeader.indexOf('(') + 1, groupHeader.length - 2);
    data.addRows([
      [lable, parseInt(value)]
    ]);
  })

  var chart = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);

});
```

Result what I am getting is below.. which is only team and count

[image]

Webpart:

[image]

I'm using below code to get the number from .ms-vb2.. but it is looping from start where as I need to loop within a specific team

```js
   var arrayList1=$("div[WebPartId='"+dataWebPartId + "'] td.ms-vb2:contains('Sum')");
   
   $.each(arrayList1, function(i,f){
    var sumvalue=$(f).text();
    //alert(sumvalue);
    var trid = $(f).attr('id');
    alert(trid );

   })
```

Comment: What is the question and specific problem? What are expected results? When you update question with those items also include sample of html being parsed

Comment: I am trying to loop thru the webpart and get the sum of Manual, Automation and saved for respective teams

I'm using below code to get the number from .ms-vb2.. but it is looping from start where as I need to loop within a specific team

   var arrayList1=$("div[WebPartId='"+dataWebPartId + "'] td.ms-vb2:contains('Sum')");
   
   $.each(arrayList1, function(i,f){
    var sumvalue=$(f).text();
    //alert(sumvalue);
    var trid = $(f).attr('id');
    alert(trid );

   })

Comment: where's the html sample code? Can't troubleshoot an image

Comment: I've inserted in my question

Comment: sorry I don't see any html code. Can't help much sort out the javascript without some html input to work with